# How many 12 V 100 Ah batteries do I need for overnight?

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, charge

I actually want to upgrade my existing solar power system at home with new set of batteries that could live up the night when solar arrays are unable to charge but I am getting confused on how many I actually need to achieve this. My current inverter max draw is 1500 W though I am planning to replace it with 3000 W along with new battery replacements

What I have currently are:

- Fridge: uses 0.48kWh within 16 hours from sundown till next sunrise the next day
- PC: uses 0.308kWh within 8 hours starting from sundown
- a 5W light bulb
- a Internet modem
- a few number of phone chargers

As for battery decay over time, the most optimal time I guess for replacement is around every 3 to 4 years.

Comment: capitalization of units does matter. I'll correct this here, but for the future: please get used to writing Watt and Ampere with a capital W or A; this get's really important as soon as your formulas contain things like milliampere (mA), megaohm (MΩ), and kilometers (km).

Comment: You're also confusing units in general: The power your fridge uses is in W or kW. The energy it uses in total over a certain time is in Wh or kWh. You'll need to edit your question to clarify what you meant, because I can only assume that your fridge has a power of 480 W, and not 30 W consumed over 16 hours (30 W · 16 h = 480 Wh = 0.48 kWh), but *we cannot know that*.

Comment: Capitalisation matters: @MarcusMüller: Agreed, but SI convention is that units named after a person are lowercase when spelled out and capitalised when abbreviated. See your first comment!

Comment: Aside from Marcus's comments for consistent units (in watt-hours, not watts), how efficient is your inverter that steps it up from 12VDC to 120VAC? how much safety margin do you want to have, and how long do you want this system to last (I.E. if batteries decay at 10% capacity / year, plan on replacing in X years)?

Comment: Your fridge doesn't run all the time, but it should have specs of it's daily energy consumption.

Comment: @user3528438 good luck with those – they are given for some fictional environmental conditions, some fictional usage pattern of the fridge, and some fictional properties of the items within. Pretty sure you'd need to design this based on measurements with at least 50% error margin.

Comment: @Transistor aaaah yeah. Got me.

Comment: When I get the optimal number of batteries needed for my scenario I would just probably double the number of batteries in actual to have it live up another day when some unforseen weather occurs.

Comment: Those batteries need to be special deep discharge batteries, not common car batteries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, with your clarifications, this becomes easy:

```
  480 Wh Fridge
+ 308 Wh PC
+  80 Wh = 50 W · 16 h light bulb (christ! get LED lights)
+~ 50 Wh "Stuff" for 16 h
========
  918 Wh
```

So, you need 918 Wh of energy on your net.

A 12 V, 100 Ah battery has a nominal capacity of 12 V · 100 Ah = 1200 Wh. But you can't assume that's true – batteries age, and are load-dependent. So, we'll easily have to "reduce" that number to ca 800 Wh for "reliability" reasons.

Then, you have non-perfect voltage conversion efficiency. Let's say, 85%, that'd be pretty good for 12V –> 120V or 240V, whatever your devices use. 
Incorporating that efficiency, your primary energy usage would be ca 1080 Wh.

That's more than 1 battery, and less than 2. I'd argue with 3 you'd be on the safe side.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation made me understand well and probably add up more expecting there would be more stuff to come in later.

Comment: Additionally you don't want to fully discharge lead acid batteries ... shallower discharges let them live longer. At 2, you'd be discharging just over 50% which is OK for deep discharge but 3 or even 4 should last longer. Also : what do you do on a cloudy day?